# Apache Memory leakage while using camel-server

Tags: rest, tomcat, apache-camel, drools

I am using camel to configure rest end points in my application.
While adding all the files does not give any problem to the project which is working fine till the point I edit camel-server.xml ,please note that I am updating knowledge-service.xml as this is where the rest point uri should hit. The moment I update camel-server.xml , deployment of WAR files in tomcat starts throwing following error :

SEVERE: The web application [/app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.drools.core.common.UpgradableReentrantReadWriteLock$1] (value [org.drools.core.common.UpgradableReentrantReadWriteLock$1@3968e529]) and a value of type [int[]] (value [[I@159d0431]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

Comment: I resolved it by myself , for any one reading this thread the problem was with the mapping of drl file with the java file. This can be checked in the log file.